# Routing in a simple lan with DHCP

Tags: routing

i'm new to networking and got me a second pc that is connected to my router with wlan and my main pc is connected with a lan cable. One has an IP of 192.168.0.3 and the other has an IP like 192.168.0.73 but i'm not able to ping from one to the other, he tells me he can't reach the network. now my question is what does i have to add to my routing table to make this work ? does both pc's need change in it's routing table and if what for a route does i have to add ?

best regards,
rocketmagnet

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following information: (1) What kind of router is this? Is it one provided by your ISP, or your own? (2) Which computer has which IP, and which computer are you trying to do the PING on? (3) What OS is each using? (4) Are you using a software firewall? If so, which one? (5) What are the _exact_ commands you are using, and the _exact_ error messages you are seeing?

Comment: (6) What "netmask" is configured on both computers? Are _both_ of them using DHCP?

Answer (score 0):

as they are in the same subnet, no routing is needed. Are you sure the firewall isn't blocking ping?